# Using Elixir module from Erlang fails

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am trying to use in Erlang module a beam-file compiled from Elixir source. It raises error when I run Erlang node but I can use the code directly from Elixir.

Elixir module:

```
defmodule Recursion do
  def print_multiple_times(msg, n) when n <= 1 do
    IO.puts msg
  end

  def print_multiple_times(msg, n) do
    IO.puts msg
    print_multiple_times(msg, n - 1)
  end
end
```

Erlang module:

```
-module(use_recur).
-define(elixir__recursion, 'Elixir.Recursion').

-export([hey/0]).

hey() ->
    ?elixir__recursion:print_multiple_times("Hello!", 3).
```

Compile both:

> $ rm -f *.beam 
>   $ elixirc recursion.ex
>   $ erlc use_recur.erl

Run Erlang:

> $ erl -run use_recur hey -run init stop -noshell {"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{'Elixir.IO',puts,["Hello!"],[]},{'Elixir.Recursion',print_multiple_times,2,[{file,"recursion.ex"},{line,7}]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
>   init terminating in do_boot ({undef,[{Elixir.IO,puts,Hello!,[]},{Elixir.Recursion,print_multiple_times,2,[{*},{*}]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})
>
> Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Elixir script:

```
Recursion.print_multiple_times "Hello!", 3
```

Runs successfully:

```
$ elixir elx_recur.exs  
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
```

Why does it happen? I'd say Erlang's output should be the same.

Comment: You probably need to add the directory containing beam files for Elixir to `erl` using `-pa` (e.g. `erl -pa /path/to/elixir/ebin ...`). The error means Erlang could not find the `'Elixir.IO'` module.

Comment: Alexanders-MacBook-Air:~ alexander$ erl -pa /usr/local/Cellar/elixir/1.4.5/lib/elixir/ebin -run use_recur hey -run init stop -noshell
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Alexanders-MacBook-Air:~ alexander$ ls  /usr/local/Cellar/elixir/1.4.5/lib/elixir/ebin/ | grep Elixir.String.beam
Elixir.String.beam

Comment: Can you repost the comment as an answer so I could mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that Erlang could not find a module named `'Elixir.IO'`. This module is part of core Elixir. You'll need to add the `ebin` folder of your Elixir installation to Erlang's load path using `-pa` (or other similar flags like `-pz`) to make Erlang load Elixir's core libraries, as that folder contains the compiled `.beam` files of Elixir core, including `Elixir.IO.beam`.

```
erl -pa /path/to/elixir/ebin ...
```